# Unable to use classpath or relative path to read json payload data

Tags: karate

I have written a Karate scenario where my login is performed from a separate .feature file. I have the following directory structure:

> src/test/java/feature/common/common.feature

When i want to call the above common feature file from another feature file which is in different folder (as below) it does not work:

> src/test/java/feature/tests/test.feature

I have tried the following:

1.

> - callonce read('feature/common/common.feature')
>     and it does not work.

2. If i were to use classpath how would i write this call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `classpath:` you will be able to access contents inside `src/test/java` if you follow standard [karate workspace structure](https://github.com/intuit/karate#folder-structure)

Inorder to call / read,

```
* call read('classpath:feature/common/common. feature')
```

simply `src/test/java` can be replaced with `classpath:`

[Refer reading files](https://github.com/intuit/karate#reading-files) from karate document for more